# Windows 7 Зеркалирование

Tags: windows-7

Извиняюсь сразу за то, что размещаю здесь этот вопрос, но под большим сомнением, что мне быстро ответят на руткоде, если ответят вообще из-за небольшого количества участников(хотя вопрос разместил и там). Если сочтете нужным удаляйте.

Собственно проблема:имеется в наличии windows 7 Ultimate, ведро с полуаппаратным raid. Два неодинаковых по размеру диска 250 и 320 гб. Как текущую конфигурацию пересадить не теряя информации на raid(думаю скорее всего не получится так как диски разные) или lvm или что-нибудь подобное, главное чтобы было зеркалирование.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается все можно - [GPT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table)

Answer (score 0):

Если черпать информацию из описания зеркального рэйда то никак... хотя я не спец в данных вопросах, возможно способы и есть)

Comment: Да и мне так кажется, что надо мутить с динамическими томами. Сейчас мучаюсь с акронисом, там используется gpt, суть технологии мне не ясна, пытаюсь сделать по-нему зеркалирование ругается, на ошибку избыточности.

Comment: не в тему но всеже, а не проще ли 2 винта одинаковых взять?